# How to add place holder In DropDownList in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to use the place holder in DropDown but it's not taking. please help to find out how to add the placeholder in DropDown List :

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewData["Category"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class="flexselect form-control" ,@placeholder="---Select---"})
```

Comment: Which framework are you using? asp.net or something else? Please us the proper tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for `placeholder` you don't need to use `@` at the beginning of it, '@' is only for `class`. for `DropDownList` set default text:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewData["Category"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "---Select---", new { @class="flexselect form-control"})
```